# How to determine whether a vertex of a simple polygon is convex

Tags: euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to understand the ear clipping algorithm for triangulation of a simple polygon G on the Euclidian plane.

It checks whether a vertex of G is convex;
Let p, q, r be consecutive 3 vertices of G.
q is said to be convex if the internal angle between the edges (p, q) and (q,r) is less than 180 degrees.

My question is: How do you determine computationally if q is convex?

Comment: @T.Bongers The point is to determine whether the angle is internal.

Comment: @T.Bongers I don't understand. Would you elaborate?

Comment: The same three non-colinear vertices $p,q,r$ can appear consecutively either in a polygon where the internal angle is less than $180$ degrees or in one where the internal angle is more than $180$ degrees (reflexive).  You don't have sufficient information.

Comment: @hardmath What do you mean  by "You don't have sufficient information"? The ear clipping algorithm determines if a vertex is convex or not. I just don't know how.

Comment: The ear-clipping algorithm works on the entire polygon, not just three consecutive vertices.

Comment: @hardmath Of course. So?

Comment: You are in possession of my argument.  Just giving me three consecutive vertices, I cannot tell whether the internal angle they form is reflexive or not.

Comment: @hardmath A simple polygon G is defined by a sequence of vertices. This is all the information you need. Let p be any vertex of G. The algorithm determines if p is convex or not. I would like to know how.

Comment: It reduces to the question of whether a point is inside or outside the polygon.

Comment: @hardmath How do you determine it?

Comment: The winding number is one wsy.

Comment: @hardmath The problem is that you need to prove that G has a point inside of it. The Jordan curve theorem ensures that, but I don't want to invoke such a non-trivial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is for arbitrary consecutive vertices, in which case you do need to know that the polygon has an interior and an exterior to make the question of whether it is a convex angle a meaningful one. Once you have that, the following method can be easily shown to give you the answer.

> Begin at the bottommost vertex and walk along the polygon starting with the rightmost incident edge. The interior is always on the left of the walk, so you can identify which angles along the way are convex (interior angle less than $180$ degrees) and which are concave simply by seeing which are left-turns and which are right-turns.

It is easy to prove that this works. At the start, there is a straight path from the vertex to infinity on the right, so the interior is on the left. Take any consecutive vertices $A,B,C,D$ in order along the walk such that the interior is on the left of the subpath $ABC$. Let $B',C'$ respectively be points that are sufficiently close to $B,C$ on the left of the subpaths $ABC,BCD$. Then $B',C'$ are connected by a straight path not intersecting the polygon. How close is sufficient? Less than the minimum distance from a vertex to a non-incident edge, which would mean that $B',C'$ are close enough to $BC$ that $B'C'$ cannot cut any edge of the polygon since no vertex besides $B,C$ is so close to $BC$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $a\in G$ (in the interior) and $L$ the line by $p$ and $r$. If $q$ and $a$ are in the same semiplane respect to $L$, $q$ are not convex.

To check this, see (if exist or not) the intersection of $L$ with the segment $aq$

Comment: How do you find an interior point of G computationally?

Comment: If G is finite (finite vertex), with the right hand's rule

Comment: I don't understand. Would you elaborate?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: You can test if a given point belongs to the interior of G by using such algorithms. But to ensure that such a point does exist. you need to prove it. How do you prove it?

Comment: @MakotoKato exist because the area( measure) is positive and the interior is open (for nondegenerated polygons)

Comment: How do you prove your first assertion?